# Bad mysql install: mysqld doesn't exist so I can't run it, and pacman won't uninstall it

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, mysql, manjaro

I installed mysql this morning, and when I ran `mysql`, I got the following output:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Further investigation shows that the file `mysqld` does not exist on my computer, so I'm unable to start it as a service.

I have the following output of `find / -name "*mysqld*"`:

```
/var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.libmysqld\x2eso.1000.b9720ff4822e4d6289897ed2226135d8.1804.1580573044000000.lz4
/home/mike/.cache/yay/mysql/mysqld_service.patch
/home/mike/.tldr/cache/pages/common/mysqldump.md
/home/mike/.tldr/cache/pages.pt-BR/common/mysqldump.md
/home/mike/.tldr/cache/pages.pt_BR/common/mysqldump.md
/usr/include/mysql/mysqld_error.h
/usr/include/mysql/server/mysqld_error.h
/usr/include/mysql/server/private/mysqld_default_groups.h
/usr/include/mysql/server/mysqld_ername.h
/usr/lib/libmysqld.so
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_mysqldiff
/usr/bin/mysqldump
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

I installed it using `yay` and selected `aur/mysql`.

Running `sudo pacman -Rs mysql` has the following output:

```
error: target not found: mysql
```

If I run `which mysql` it is at `/usr/bin/mysql`

I still have all the build files in `~/.cache`, so I can look through those if anyone has any suggestions. They contain references and supposed installation locations for `mysqld`, but it is nowhere to be found.

For reference, I'm running Manjaro i3 Edition

I'm at my wits end. I can't get mysql to work, and I can't uninstall it either.

Comment: As a side note avoid using `which`. Use `type` instead. The file `/usr/bin/mysql` is the mysql client binary and not the server. This is i.e. to connect to a mysql server using `mysql -u username --password`.  What you should do is install the `mariadb` package. Something like `sudo pacman -Syu && sudo pacman -S mysql` and choose `mariadb` there. Finally start the service `systemctl start mysqld`

Comment: if it was installed using yay, can yay uninstall it?